# Filter the users name in the list of admin / people of organic groups Drupal 7

Tags: organic-groups, forms

I have a lot of users in several organic groups, I need filter the users by username to acept or deny join to group.

Generic url group page: `group/node/[nid]/admin/people`

I appreciate any guidance to filter users (contributed module, hook_form_alter...) or disable pagination in this page.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see `admin/structure/views/view/og_members_admin/edit/default`

In og 7.x-2.0-rc1 exists this functionality